# contractible closed geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

Very often I encounter a statement but can't find the exact reference: on a closed surface with non-positive constant curvature (e.g. a flat torus or higher genus surface with constant negative curvature), there does not exist any **contractible** non-constant closed geodesic. First, is this statement correct? Second, (if it is correct), is it simply from Cartan-Hadamard theorem? I am grateful for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gauss-Bonnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem) gives a proof: If a closed geodesic is contractible, it bounds a disk, whose total curvature is $2\pi$. It follows the curvature is positive somewhere.

Comment: when you use is a geodesic for apply gauss-bonnet, if the curve is contractible but not geodesic, same argument is valid? thanks